# Data type of a MAC address?

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON data file

```
[{"entityClass":"DefaultEntityClass","mac":["00:00:00:00:00:02"],"ipv4":[],"vlan":[],"attachmentPoint":[{"switchDPID":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02","port":1,"errorStatus":null}],"lastSeen":1398463052792}]
```

and I want to get the "mac". but I don't know which data type I have to use, since the server
says that it is neither a long nor a string value. Which datatype is this "mac" ?.

my code:

```
try {
        JSONArray arraydevice = new JSONArray(devicesJson);
        JSONObject obj = arraydevice.getJSONObject(0);
        long mac = obj.getLong("mac");
        System.out.println("The mac address of the host is " + mac);

    } 
catch (JSONException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have to use org.json? :/ It's the "worst" JSON library in existence

Comment: I just found it while googling. Why is it considered bad ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
["00:00:00:00:00:02"]
```

is an array with one element, and that element is a string.

```
String mac = obj.getJSONArray("mac").getString(0);
```

though it would probably be a good idea to check the `.length()` of the array before you try and `get` anything out of it, in case it turns out to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

From the JSON Schema the MAC Address looks like an Array of String. However if you have a Class structure defined on the server , you can use that for converting the JSON into an object.